# Are there any C# libraries that wrap Xmpp Jingle or wrap Xmpp Jingle libraries written in another language

Tags: c#, xmpp, wrapper, voip, sip

I am looking to add the functionality provided by jingle to my C# based Application as an alternative to implementing a SIP client.

After some research the Xmpp Standards Foundation website only listed the following libraries for jingle

- libjingle (C/C++)
- Smack (Java)
- Telepathy Gabble (C)
- yjingle (C++)

Is anyone aware of any libraries that are either available or in development that implement jingle in C# or that simply wrap any of the libraries listed above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a list of XMPP library 
http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/